# Review panel loses items-per-page links when page size is set to 50

Tags: bug, review

Starting off at 15 items per page, it shows:

[image: so-pages-15]

Changing to 30 items per page, it still shows:

[image: so-pages-30]

But changing to 50 items per page, it disappears:

[image: so-pages-50]

Comment: I can reproduce this on Stack Overflow, but not on Meta Stack Overflow. I am using Safari 5.1.2 on Mac OS X 10.7.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like the problem is not the number of items per page, but the number of pages.

The critical amount seems to be 2. If there are 2 or less pages, the items-per-page links do not show up.

- [Review Late answers - day - 50 per page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers?s=1&pagesize=50&filter=day&no-random=1) shows the error. Right now, there is only 1 page.
- [Review Late answers - day - 30 per page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers?s=1&pagesize=30&filter=day&no-random=1) shows the error. Right now, there are 2 pages.
- [Review Late answers - day - 15 per page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers?s=1&pagesize=30&filter=day&no-random=1) does **not** show the error. Right now, there are 3 pages.
- [Review First Questions - day - 50 per page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions?s=1&pagesize=50&filter=day&no-random=1) does **not** show the error. Right now, there are 14 pages.

This also affects SuperUser and Meta.